# Java: Invalid Character Constant error occurring

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm try to make a notification. I saw [a little tutorial](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/create-new-message-notification-pop-up.html) but something is not working for me.

```
JLabel messageLabel = new JLabel('<HtMl>'+message);
```

> "Invalid Character Constant"

Why is this error occurring?

Comment: try to use double quotes `""`.  double quotes are for string, and single quotes are for character constant `'`

Comment: Can you post the tutorial, so we can check if it really uses `'` instead of `"`?

Comment: @TOM Of course there is : [link](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/create-new-message-notification-pop-up.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Funny to see, that the tutorial is untested :D.

Answer (score 1):

You need double quotes the single quotes is for char literals.

```
JLabel messageLabel = new JLabel("<HtMl>"+message);
```

or

```
JLabel messageLabel = new JLabel('l'+message);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use double quotes instead of single quotes to resolve your problem.